# unset a group of PHP sessions

Tags: php, session, unset

I recently ran into a strange problem with PHP `$_SESSION` variables.

On `renewal-check.php` we retreive a user's information from the database and save it like this:

```
$_SESSION['parent']['mailing_address'];
$_SESSION['parent']['home_phone'];
$_SESSION['parent']['cell_phone'];
```

They are then asked to enter one of those values to confirm their identity. If they cannot confirm, `$_SESSION['parent']` is `unset()` with `unset($_SESSION['parent']);`

However, running `echo $_SESSION['parent']['somevalue']` still gives data. How do I unset all session variables under `$_SESSION['parent']` if `unset()` isn't working?

Example code:

`page1.php`

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['parent']['mailing_address'] = "somevalue";
$_SESSION['parent']['home_phone'] = "somevalue";
$_SESSION['parent']['cell_phone'] = "somevalue";
```

`page2.php`

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['parent']);
echo $_SESSION['parent']['cell_phone'];
```

Page2.php still outputs data, even after `$_SESSION['parent']` was unset.

Comment: Please provide a little example to reproduce your error.

Comment: You are doing something wrong. No demo script - no solution.

Comment: @Rizier123 See my edit

Comment: @pattyd Can't reproduce it with the provided code. 1) Have you tested **only** the provided code above, to make sure it's not something else, which you don't show us here. 2) Also make sure you have error reporting turned on, to make sure you don't get some other errors.

Comment: @pattyd Restarting the server is always a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unset($_SESSION['var'])` is the correct function to use.

Have you initialized the session with `session_start()` ?

If you have, there might be an issue with your PHP installation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The problem was that the code was positioned wrong before the echo, so it echoed and then unset. This was due to one of the gui elements on the page. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try re-instantiating it

```
$_SESSION['parent'] = array();
```